# Windshield replacement damaged molding?

Tags: car, repair, windshield, windshield-molding, rubber

I just recently had a windshield replaced by safelite. I noticed when I got the car back, both the driver side and passenger side plastic molding at the bottom of the windshield is separated about a quarter inch from the new windshield. I can't remember if it was like this prior to my windshield replacement. I was wondering if I should say something to the shop. Below is a video showing the amount of play in this plastic/rubber piece.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/ezc4hih2KfqDzAhV9

https://photos.app.goo.gl/haymhqb58JW28Shk9

Comment: Get it fixed. Satellite warranties all their work. If they messed with it, they'll make it right ... at least they did for me.